# Is there a way to choose only the properties of an array of objects which are different from each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

Let's say I've got this array of objects.

```
let cars = [
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "minivan",
    capacity: 7
  },  
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "ferrari",
    capacity: 3
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    type: "bike",
    capacity: 1
  }
```

Is there a way to only get the values "purple" and "green" in an array once without repeating?

Comment: Well, that's your whole array, there are nothing to do. Show us some good input sample along with expected output, plus your attempts (even with pseudo code) to solve this problem. (Hint : You may need to use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) )

Comment: Or perhaps you only want the property `color`? In that case, [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do the job

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for

```
const colors = cars.map(car => car.color);
const unique = [...new Set(colors)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let cars = [
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "minivan",
    capacity: 7
  },  
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "ferrari",
    capacity: 3
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    type: "bike",
    capacity: 1
  }
]

let colors = [];
cars.forEach(car => {
  if(!(colors.includes(car.color))) colors.push(car.color);
});

console.log(colors);
```

If you need the whole `car` then just push `car` instead of `car.color`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var _ = require("lodash");
const cars = [
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "minivan",
    capacity: 7
  },  
  {
    color: "purple",
    type: "ferrari",
    capacity: 3
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    type: "bike",
    capacity: 1
  }
]
_.uniqBy(cars, 'color')
// Array (2 items)
// 0: Object {capacity: 7, color: "purple" , type: "minivan"}
// 1: Object {capacity: 1, color: "green" , type: "bike"}
```